# Arriving at a different port of entry in the same state in USA?

Tags: usa, customs-and-immigration, san-francisco, los-angeles

I am a girl in my early twenties traveling to USA from India and in my visa application I have provided the contact address for a relative in San Francisco, and their invitation letter. I would like to visit LA first. Will I face problems during immigration if I land in LA (with an immediate on wards ticket to SF)? I dont plan to get on the flight from LA to SFO.

Initially I was planning to fly to SFO from India and then fly to LA immediately after completing immigration at SFO airport.

Answer (score 6):

You can enter the US at any point, unless there is an [annotation on your visa](http://blogs.usembassy.gov/philippines/visa-annotation-niv/) stating that you must enter at a specific port of entry.

Keep in mind that your purpose for entering the US must be consistent with the purposes allowed by the type of visa you have. If you enter for a purpose not allowed by the visa type (e.g. to take employment when you have a B1/B2 visa) then you may be refused entry and returned to your departure point.