# TRANSIT VISA IN US for a F1 visa holder

Tags: transit

I have a F1 visa and I hold an Indian passport. I am going to the US for the first time. Do I need a transit visa while changing flights within the US?

Comment: Please edit your question and capitalize it properly and add punctuation to make it more readable.

Comment: What is your final destination?

Answer (score 2):

An F-1 visa [allows you to travel to the United States](https://travel.state.gov/content/visas/en/study-exchange/student.html). If you are traveling to the US pursuant to your visa (i.e. to study), then you do not need a transit visa because you are [allowed to enter the US at any port of entry](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/62007/arriving-at-a-different-port-of-entry-in-the-same-state-in-usa). E.g. if you are studying in Seattle, you can arrive in the USA in New York with your F-1 visa and board a plane to Seattle there. If you are traveling outside of the window of the F-1 visa and just want to transit (e.g. travel from the UK to Japan with a transit in the USA), you probably need a transit visa.

Comment: I would like to strengthen the statement a bit: It is also important that if the OP travels to US to study there, he/she must *NOT* enter on a transit visa. The institution that admitted him/her needs to see that he was "stamped in" using the F-1 visa in order to allow him/her to pursue his/her studies.